# How to increase the font size in the Visual Studio 2015 Enter SQL Query box?

Tags: visual-studio

I am having trouble figuring out what to adjust to make the font size bigger for the text in the SSIS "Enter SQL Query" box. This is for VS2015 Professional.

If someone can give me a tip, I'd appreciate it!